# Data not displayed in jList method from database

Tags: java, database, swing, jlist

I am Using the following code :

```
DefaultListModel dModel = (DefaultListModel)jList1.getModel();

txtBilln.enableInputMethods(false);

try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Drvier");
    Connection con = (Connection)
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jns","root","jns");
    Statement stmt = null ;

    ResultSet rs = null ; 

    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM ELEB";

    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

    while (rs.next()){
        String bno= rs.getString("billn");
        String cnamme = rs.getString("cname");
        dModel.addElement(bno + "-" + cnamme); 
    }
    jList1.setModel(dModel);

    con.close();

}catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();              
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. The code above looks (somewhat) fine. For better help, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use hard coded values also, instead of db data, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: The call `jList1.setModel(dModel);` is unnecessary btw since you are updating the model of that `jList1`. And I would fix the typo in `"com.mysql.jdbc.Drvier"` as well

Comment: Did you add a System.out.println(...) to make sure data was returned from the SQL query???